# LINQ orderby not working in Swedish culture

Tags: linq

How to set LINQ orderby based on CurrentUICulture

```
  var actorQuery = (from actor in actorList
                              where !actor.IsLocked
                              select new { Id = actor.Id, Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", actor.Name, actor.BusinessId) }).OrderBy(actor => actor.Name);
```

Comment: Linq to what? Objects or EFs. database? First: change thread culture. Second: change table sorting.

Answer (score 0):

The order is determined by `CurrentCulture` not `CurrentUICulture`
Example:

```
var a = new string[] {"å","ä","ö","a","b","c"};
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sv-SE");
a.OrderBy(x => x).Dump(); //a,b,c,å,ä,ö

System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
a.OrderBy(x => x).Dump(); //a,ä,å,b,c,ö
```

So just set `CurrentCulture` at the same time you set `CurrentUICulture`